# Grant root access without using SuperSU like utility

Tags: root-access, superuser

I wonder if it is possible to let every application work with elevated privileges without a utility (such as SuperSU or SuperUser) to manage such requests... :/

Comment: Yes, just don't use such an app and don't use a `su` binary customized to depend on it.

Comment: What is a su binary?

Comment: See Wikipedia: [su (Unix)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_(Unix))

Comment: So you mean that the apps that come bundled with SuperSU, are modified in a way that they depend on SSU for obtaining permissions?

Comment: 1) It is possible as Matthew stated, 2) `1)` is incomplete because app must request root privilege to work, 3) not using an intercepting app like SuperSU would be one of the most dangerous things you can ever do to compromise your device.